# Comments not displaying when feedback is true

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get my comments to display if my feedback is true, but nothing is showing, and I'm getting an empty array. Some comments have `feedback = true`.

```php
public function getComments(Post $post)
{
    foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    {
        if($comment->feedback == true)
        {
            dd($comment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know what the feedback zone gives us first! if($comment->feedback == 'true') OR if(isset($comment->feedback))

Comment: Please share your Post.php model file for a better understanding